# How to work with a range of prices in Android + PHP json request

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I have an app that is bringing the apartments from the MySQL database according with some conditions (state, city, price, garage, ...)

I was reading about range, BETWEEN and arrays in PHP scripts but I could not find a way to solve this problem because besides bringing the values from the database, I need to show the apartment in my listview only if its price is in between the range of prices:

I have a spinner in my Android application that has some range of prices ($500.000 - $1.000.000, $1.000.000 - $2.000.000, $2.000.000 - $5.000.000) and the conditions to show the apartments are the following:

```
new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
pDialog.dismiss();

// Parsing json
for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
    try {
        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
        Event event = new Event();
        event.setImovel_id(obj.getString("imovel_id"));
        event.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("arquivo"));
        event.setNegocio(obj.getString("negocio"));
        event.setImovel(obj.getString("imovel"));
        event.setMobilia(obj.getString("mobilia"));
        event.setGaragem(obj.getString("garagem"));
        event.setPreco(obj.getString("preco"));

        city = obj.getString("city");
        statee = obj.getString("state");
        checkNegocio = obj.getString("negocio");
        checkImovel = obj.getString("imovel");
        checkMobilia = obj.getString("mobilia");
        checkGaragem = obj.getString("garagem");
        checkPreco = obj.getString("preco");

        if(estado.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(statee) && 
            cidade.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(city) && 
            checkN.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(checkNegocio) && 
            checkI.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(checkImovel) && 
            checkM.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(checkMobilia) && 
            checkG.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(checkGaragem) && 
            checkP.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(checkPreco)){

           // adding event to events array
           eventList.add(event);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

} if(eventList.size() > 0){
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    }else{
        noEvent.setText("No results");                              
    }

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

and this is the PHP file for the json encode

```
<?php

$link_list = array();
$link = array();

include_once 'db_connect.php';


$sql = "SELECT * FROM iMoveis";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

$link['imovel_id'] = $row['imovel_id'];

$link['arquivo'] = $row['arquivo'];
$link['state'] = $row['state'];
$link['city'] = $row['city'];
$link['negocio'] = $row['negocio'];
$link['imovel'] = $row['imovel'];
$link['mobilia'] = $row['mobilia'];

$link['garagem'] = $row['garagem'];
$link['preco'] = $row['preco'];



array_push($link_list, $link);  

}

echo json_encode($link_list, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
?>
```

$row['preco'] brings the price of the apartment from the db.

What would be the best way of doing this? Is there a way of doing that in my java class? I think it would be easier. Thanks in advance.

**Edit**:
I need to show the apartment that is within the average of prices given by spinner. I have the price of the apartment as a single value in my db (for example $1.200.000). But the spinner has a range of price on each item to be selected:

- 1st = $1.000.000 to $2.000.000
- 2nd = $2.000.000 to $5.000.000 and so on..

What I need is to show the apartment on the listview only if the database value is within the avarage of the spinner. What the spinner sends is $1.000.000 to $2.000.000 and the json prints only $1.200.000. So it does not match and does not show me anything on the listview. It should be shown because $1.200.000 is within $1.000.000 to $2.000.000. Sorry but I cannot send printscreen to give you a better view

Comment: What exactly is the question? You really ought to treat these as two separate problems.

Comment: i think i know the solution to your problem but i am unable to get what do you exactly want

Comment: please take a look at my "edit"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by myself changing the spinners options. Set new spinners with min and max values and if the price is between these values, I show the apartments.